# Dependency injection (Quarkus/java)

Tags: java, dependency-injection

коллеги! Подскажите,пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался с подобным. Есть некий класс в который пытаюсь инжектить различные бины. Как пример такого класса:

```
public class TestClass implements Callback {

@Inject
TestClassRepository repository;

//только методы класса TestClass...
}
```

Но при этом, при попытке использовать методы бина 'repository' в методах класса TestClass я получаю NullPointerException.
Класс TestClassRepository помечен аннотациями '@ApplicationScoped' и '@Startup'.
А сам класс 'TestClass' используется в методе другого класса через оператор new:

```
Flyway.configure().collbacks(new TestClass()).load();
```

Возможно ли в принципе инжектить бины в класс,который создается через оператор 'new'?

Comment: Можно. Надо просто явно вызвать код, который заинжетит нужное в экземпляре класса. В конструктор можете этот код поместить. Точнее не скажу, этот DI не пробовал

Comment: Через оператор new ничего не инжектируется. TestClass сам должен быть бином, и должен быть сам инжектирован. Или же можно воспользоваться специальным cdi api, Если речь собственно о CDI. то `Flyway.configure().collbacks(CDI.current().select(TestClass.class).get()).load();` Но это не всё, надо выполгить ещё ряд требований

Comment: Здравствуйте,Сергей! А где можно ознакомиться с рядом соответствующих требований?

Comment: @Disteonne в гугле:)

Comment: Принято. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Главное правильно понимать `lifecycle` таких бинов, и в случае необходимости уничтожать ссылки на них (вручную), чтобы постараться избежать утечки памяти.